# SignalR Disconnect method is not invoked on Internet Disconnection

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ASP.NET CORE Web API .net 6.0 application with SignalR WebSocket hub and JS Client for SignalR. And when I am disconecting from internet SignalR disconnect method is not calling. I tried to config timeouts but still not working

Disconnect signalR when there is no internet

Comment: It will raise disconnected but not immediately. There's configurable a threshold (30 seconds by default) that SignalR will wait (after the underlying tcp connection has gone away and this isn't immediate either) before it considers a client disconnected. If the connection drops and reconnects before the configured timeout then it won't raise OnDisconnected.

Comment: If you never see it being raised in some cases after waiting for a while then it might have some errors. Here are two links might help you: [DisconnectTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#disconnecttimeout), [SignalR Client Disconnected Event not called when internet connection is lost](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3919).

Comment: You can print the log after disconnection to see if it automatically reconnects. If you don't find the problem, please provide a minimal reproducible example.